# Why the black background does not show from my code?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create two balls that are falling against a black background, but the black background does not show. When I remove the two balls, the background shows. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    
    
    
     .balls{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: fixed;
      background-color: #efebf2;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-name: fall;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      }
      
     .ball1{
     left:30%;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     }
     
     .ball2{
     left:60%;
     animation-timing-function: ease-out;
     }
     
     
     @keyframes fall{
      0%{
       top:10%;
      }
      100%{
       top: 50%;
      {
     }
     
     .sky{
      height:100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: black;
      }
      
    
</head>
<body>
 <div class="sky"></div>
 <div class="balls ball1"></div>
 <div class="balls ball2"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: There's an error in your @keyframes rule, one of the brackets is the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your css: The open brace (`{`) after `top:50%;` should be a closed brace (`}`).